# how to set programmatically a MS Access column default to text that contains spaces

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, ddl

You can programmatically (VB.NET, OleDB, Jet4.0, in my case) set the default of a (string-type) MS Access databasecolumn. Create an OleDbCommand cmd with an appropriate OleDbConnection (and whatever else is needed), and set:

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> SET DEFAULT john"
```

Then

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

A problem arises when the default value should consist of more words, with spaces in between. In that case you'll get a failure unless you "quote" the default value, like so:

```
"ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> SET DEFAULT 'john doe'"
```

However, this results in having a default value in the database that also contains the quotes.
It is not a major practical issue (I trim the quotes upon retrieving them from the database, before processing the value), but I find it not elegant and wonder if there's a way to specify it properly in DDL such that the default is stored in the database without the quotes.

Any hints and clarifications are appreciated.

Comment: Can you use double-quotes: `"ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> SET DEFAULT ""john doe"""`?

Comment: Why not just change the column data type directly? ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> TEXT(10)

Comment: @Gustav: using double quotes as you suggest has the same issue: you get a default (in the database) that contains a double quote around the intended value.

Comment: @random_answer_guy: the dataTYPE of the column is already set correctly a priori. It's not the size/length of the field that is the issue but setting a default value (text) that contains spaces. Maybe I misunderstand your remark and don't see how it relates to my post/question. If so, please explain.

Comment: @Bert No that was my mistake I misunderstood what your issue was, I thought you were having trouble setting the type of the column. Re-reading this, I don't think you can do that, the default value for text fields must contain quotes. Open a table in Access, set the default field to a text column to dog with no quotes, Access adds the quotes anyway...

Comment: @random_answer_guy. Thansk for clarifying. As to your last remark: that doesn't seem the case: I did programmatically set a single-word default without any quotes - see the "simple" case in my post - and upon inspecting the database directly in MS Access I found that, indeed, there were no quotes. So: (1) yes, you can set a non-quoted string-default if it is one word, but (2) my question remains: how to do that for text that does contain spaces (if it is possible at all: I tried with parameters and all kinds of tricks, like square brackets around the value, but so far all without success.

Comment: Yep coffee not working today. I meant in regards to entering a string with spaces, but in any event, I have tried a few ways, @Gustav suggestion does work though, use double quotes for the string with spaces, and the quotes do not show in the data fields.

Comment: While you might see the quotes in the settings pane do the quotes actually get entered into your table when you create a a new record and the default value is used?